# How to make a css grid grow to contain a flexbox when using grid-auto-rows?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

In the following codepen you will see that there is a flexbox inside of a css grid. As you can see, the contents of the flexbox div are overflowing under other parts of the grid.

If I remove the CSS `grid-auto-rows:100px;` then the flexbox contents no longer overflow. However, I really want the other css grid items to be 100px tall, unless their contents are too tall to be contained within 100px.

How can I have all the css grid items default to 100px tall while having any items whose contents are taller than 100px grow to hold all of the contents?

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.wrapper { 
  display: grid; 
  grid-auto-rows: 100px; 
} 

.wrapper > div {
  border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffd8a8;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #d9480f;
}

.box2 { 
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box2 > div{
  border: 2px solid #ffa999;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffd899;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #d94899;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box1">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box2">
    Box 2
    <div class="flex1">Flex One</div>
    <div class="flex2">Flex One</div>
    <div class="flex3">Flex One</div>
    <div class="flex4">Flex One</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box3">Box 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `minmax(min, max)` function.

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.wrapper { 
  display: grid; 
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto); 
} 

.wrapper > div {
  border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffd8a8;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #d9480f;
}

.box2 { 
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box2 > div{
  border: 2px solid #ffa999;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffd899;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #d94899;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box1">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box2">
    Box 2
    <div class="flex1">Flex One</div>
    <div class="flex2">Flex One</div>
    <div class="flex3">Flex One</div>
    <div class="flex4">Flex One</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box3">Box 3</div>
</div>
```